# Can we override style binding in vue component?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

So I used vue component that have style binding in it.

Just wondering, can we override those style binding? The style is inside the component which I can't directly change its value, but I do have $emmit though feels like it's doesn't do anything in this case. I also avoid to use :deep and !important.

Comment: `deep l` is used for that purpose, why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Cmiiw @kissu, cause I think it will broken some of the css flow?  It's not a best practice, and very likely it would cause undesired effects further down the line.

Comment: I mean, we don't have any code here so it's hard to speak about "best pratice" with basically nothing. `deep` can be quite bad if you're abusing it for sure, but it's always a matter of balance. Also, it's usually more used to override 3rd party packages. CSS can also be tricky while using highly customizable slots, Vue3 fixes some of the shortcoming on that matter. Overall, I'd say that it's a question on how to organize your CSS across all of your components. You could use some state to handle that properly. SASS will not really remove complexity tbh, I'm not a huge fan of it personally.

Comment: I see, yup I think I can go with this way for now, thanks in advance for sharing your thoughts @kissu!